# fast way getting distinct property of all interconnected nodes of huge graph

Tags: neo4j

My Neo4J database currently has a little bit over 13 million nodes in it with as many edges. Simplified structure as follows (omitted most edge types)

```
User - HAS_EMAIL -> Email // is unique
     - HAS_IBAN  -> Iban  // is unique
     - HAS_PHONE -> Phone // is unique
```

I want to get all user-ids which are interconnected with each others, regardless the length of the path. This way I can

I started of with a cypher query like the following, using Neo4Js HTTP API.

```
MATCH (u:User {uid: '12345'})-[*1..]-(otherUser) 
RETURN DISTINCT otherUser
```

Using variable length pattern matching without an upper bound and especially without limit was slow as hell.

So I dug around, and found the APOC library with its `expandConfig` method.

```
MATCH (u:User {uid: '12345'})
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(c, {bfs:true, uniqueness:"NODE_GLOBAL"}) YIELD path
// Extracting the 'uid' property
RETURN extract(
  n IN (
    // We only want 'User' nodes
    filter (
      x IN NODES(path) WHERE 'User' IN labels(x)
    )
  ) | n.uid
) as uid
```

This works like a charm and returns all nodes within a few milliseconds in most cases.

It takes nearly 30 seconds when querying for a user of which I know he is "very well" connected (24k nodes with 40k edges).

**Example response**

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "columns": [
        "uid"
      ],
      "data": [
        {"row": [["9974"]], "meta": [null]},
        {"row": [["9974"]], "meta": [null]},
        {"row": [["9974"]], "meta": [null]},
        {"row": [["9974","14367"] ],"meta": [null,null]},
        {"row": [["9974","11820"] ],"meta": [null,null]},
        {"row": [["9974","11821"] ],"meta": [null,null]},
        {"row": [["9974","11822"] ],"meta": [null,null]},
        {"row": [["9974","11823"] ],"meta": [null,null]},
        {"row": [["9974","9314"] ],"meta": [null,null]},
        {"row": [["9974","9313"] ],"meta": [null,null]},
        {"row": [["9974","9317"] ],"meta": [null,null]},
        {"row": [["9974","14367"] ],"meta": [null,null]},
        {"row": [["9974","11820"] ],"meta": [null,null]},
        {"row": [["9974","11821"] ],"meta": [null,null]},
        {"row": [["9974","11822"] ],"meta": [null,null]},
        {"row": [["9974","11823"] ],"meta": [null,null]},
        {"row": [["9974","9314"] ],"meta": [null,null]},
        {"row": [["9974","9313"] ],"meta": [null,null]},
        {"row": [["9974","9317"] ],"meta": [null,null]},
        {"row": [["9974","11820","3287" ]],"meta": [null,null,null]},
        {"row": [["9974","11820","39584" ]],"meta": [null,null,null]},
        {"row": [["9974","11820","5109" ]],"meta": [null,null,null]},
        {"row": [["9974","11820","3379" ]],"meta": [null,null,null]},
        {"row": [["9974","11820","3288" ]],"meta": [null,null,null]},
        --- Snipp ---
```

Now I would like to get rid of all the duplicates, getting a result like the following

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "columns": [
        "uid"
      ],
      "data": [
        {"row": [["9974"]], "meta": [null]},
        {"row": [["14367"]], "meta": [null]},
        {"row": [["11820"]], "meta": [null]},
        {"row": [["11821"]],"meta": [null]},
        {"row": [["11822"]],"meta": [null]},
        {"row": [["11823"]],"meta": [null]},
        {"row": [["9314"]],"meta": [null]},
        {"row": [["9313"]],"meta": [null]},
        {"row": [["9317"]],"meta": [null]},
        {"row": [["14367"]],"meta": [null]},
        {"row": [["11820"]],"meta": [null]},
        {"row": [["11821"]],"meta": [null]},
        {"row": [["11822"]],"meta": [null]},
        {"row": [["11823"]],"meta": [null]},
        --- snipp ---
```

How would I accomplish this?
Nice to have: Is there a way to make this fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few adjustments which should make this faster.

For one, you're iterating over nodes(path) for all paths. There are going to be many repeated nodes in there, as common paths will be reusing the same nodes.

Since you're using NODE_GLOBAL uniqueness, the end nodes of all paths should form the whole subgraph, so we can get these as rows, and then perform the filtering for :User nodes (there's a specific syntax for checking if a node has a specific label), then get the uids.

```
MATCH (u:User {uid: '12345'})
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(c, {bfs:true, uniqueness:"NODE_GLOBAL"}) YIELD path
WITH DISTINCT LAST(NODES(path)) as user
WHERE user:User
RETURN COLLECT(user.uid) as uid
```

And if you don't want the uids in a single collection, just return `user.uid` at the end.

Comment: Querying for the big graph now only takes two seconds, freaking awesome! Thank you so much, had to giggle like a little girl :)

Comment: Glad to help, always a wonderful thing to see execution time plummet!